# Display directory and its all sub directories in treeview using jquery

Tags: jquery, treeview

Need to display directory and its all sub directories in `treeview` using `jquery` .
Display name is directory Name/file name and on click of an ite it could be open file

```
 $.ajax({
            url: "./Files/",
            success: function (data) {

                $(data).each(function () {


            },
            error: function (jqxhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                //alert("error");

                alert(errorThrown);
                alert(jqxhr.responseText);
            }
        });
```

The Problem is i  ihave to itrate `success` values.